# Getting results from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've never worked with arrays before and am trying to work out how to get the results from a 2d array.

When it was 3d array that wasn't a problem but now I need to work out the field number to make sure I'm getting the right details.
This is what used when it was a 3d array:

```
     <?php
     $userResults[] = sprintf($userRowDetails, $user['Name'], 
     $currentUser[$user['Name']], $counter, $user['Gender']);
    ?>

     $user['Name'] // this is the field name (i.e. First Name)
     $currentUser[$user['Name']] // this is the results from Name field (is Jane Doe)
```

This is what the 3d array looked like:

```
    [1] => Array
    (
    [First Name] => Jane
    [Last Name] => Doe
    [Gender] => Female
    )
```

and this is what the 2d array now looks like

```
    [0] => Array
    (
    [First Name] => Array
    (
    [1] => Jane
    [2] => Joe
    [3] => Alan
    [4] => Fran
    )
    [Last Name] => Array
(
    [1] => Doe
    [2] => Bloggs
    [3] => Jones
    [4] => 
)

    [Gender] => Array
(
    [1] => Female
    [2] => Male
    [3] => Male
    [4] => Female
)
    )
```

I just don't know how to get the results from the 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily loop an 2d array like this

```
$testArray = array(
  array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'gender' => 'Male'
  ),array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'gender' => 'Male'
  ),array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'gender' => 'Male'
  )
);

foreach($testArray as $value){
  echo $value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname'].' is a '.$value['gender'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach function for this.
Suppose your 2d array variable name is $user
You can get its value as following

```
$user = array(
  array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'Gender' => 'Male'
  ),array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'Gender' => 'Male'
  ),array(
    'Firstname' => 'Hans',
    'Lastname' => 'Muster',
    'Gender' => 'Male'
  )
);

foreach($user as $user_details){
    echo $user_details['Firstname'];
    echo $user_details['Lastname'];
    echo $user_details['Gender'];
}
```